How to determine the number and properties of converter filter elements?
the converter I used in my card design is shown in the image. I am having troubles and deficiencies in determining the filter type and elements that I should use at the input and output of the converter. Is there a rule regarding which type of filter to use when in converter filtering? How should the features and number of elements (such as capacitor capacity value and voltage value) of the filtering type used be determined? Two different filterings of the same converter are seen in the image. What are their differences? Why is one more accurate or preferable than the other? 
